# Are these 2 topologies equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ be subsets. Then we naturally give $A$ and $B$ the (subspace) topologies induced by the inclusion maps $$i : A\hookrightarrow X\qquad\qquad\text{and}\qquad\qquad j : B\hookrightarrow Y.$$
>
> What about the product $A\times B$? There are two natural options for topologizing $A\times B$, namely:
>
> - $A\times B$ is the product of the spaces $A$ and $B$, so you give it the product topology
> - first give $X\times Y$ the product topology and then observe that the underlying set of $A\times B$ is a subset of $X\times Y$, so it makes sense to give $A\times B$ the (subspace) topology induced by the inclusion map $k : A\times B\to X\times Y$.
>
> Are these two topologies on $A\times B$ the same?

Could anyone give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave the general argument (for all products, even the box product) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3511816/4280) in detail.

A more general view, based on the fact that both the subspace and the product topology are special cases of initial topologies can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1548818/4280); the result you're looking for is at the end. The whole theory outlined is standard "categorical topology", one could say.

Answer (score 1):

You can show identity between two space (same sets, different(really?) topology.) is isomorphism.

try to choose same bases of two spaces.

Hint:
$$
(U \times V) \cap (A \times B) = (U \cap A) \times (V \cap B)
$$

If you are in big trouble, you can find answer in *introduction to topology by munkres, Thm 16.3.*

Comment: which Munkers? the second edition does not contain chapter 16 at all

Comment: not chapter 16. It is in section 16 (chapter 2).

Comment: BTW it's 19.3 in the 2nd edition (still chapter 2) but its proof is an exercise (!). It's 5.4 (page 90) in the first edition, though, for 2 spaces and with proof.

Comment: we did not define the notion of basis yet, so I would like to show this without using the basis notion.